# "WHERE OR " load data in data range in Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, codeigniter

Im trying to load data between a range of data in codeigniter. 
i could not get the where statement right. The statement that i want to query is:

1- Get data if `"inv_firstdate"` is between  `$from` and `$to`
2- OR if `inv_seconddate` is between  `$from` and `$to`

I Tried the query in the code, 
i Needyour help please, any ideas?

```
$from = "20150309"; 
$to = "2015410"; 

$query = $this->db->select('*');
$query = $this->db->from('inv');
$query = $this->db->join('users', 'users.hu_id = inv.usr_id');
$query = $this->db->order_by('inv_id', 'desc');

$query = $this->db->where('hu_sponsor', $id);
$query = $this->db->where('pln_duration', 30);
$query = $this->db->where('inv_status', 1);

$query =  $this->db->where('inv_firstdate >=', $from);
$query =  $this->db->where('inv_firstdate <=', $to);
$query =  $this->db->or_where('inv_seconddate >=', $to);
$query =  $this->db->or_where('inv_seconddate <=', $from);
```

Comment: why you assigning each line to $query?

Comment: What do you suggest about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `where` and `or_where` condition together.`or_where` only can be used where only OR queries need.You can use this to solve your problem

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('inv');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.hu_id = inv.usr_id');
    $this->db->order_by('inv_id', 'desc');

    $this->db->where('hu_sponsor', $id);
    $this->db->where('pln_duration', 30);
    $this->db->where('inv_status', 1);

    $this->db->where('((inv_firstdate >='. $from.' AND inv_firstdate <= '.$to.') OR (inv_seconddate <='. $to.' AND inv_seconddate >= '.$from.'))');
    $results=$this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
$query =  $this->db->where('((inv_firstdate >= ', $from, FALSE);
$query =  $this->db->where('inv_firstdate <= ' . $to . ')', NULL, FALSE);
$query =  $this->db->or_where('(inv_seconddate >= ', $to, FALSE);
$query =  $this->db->where('inv_seconddate <= '. $from . '))', NULL, FALSE);
```

Or this :

```
$query =  $this->db->where('((inv_firstdate >= ' . $from . ' AND inv_firstdate <= ' . $to . ') OR (inv_seconddate >= ' . $to . ' AND inv_seconddate <= ' . $from . '))');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, the synax is correct but it does not excute the OR_WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your date formats in the db but regardless when your queries get complex in my experience you end up writing more code using ci active record than pure SQL thus defeating the point of it. Just use `$this->db->query("")` with your various conditions built the old fashioned way. You will save probably 60% in lines, it will be more readable and will actually work. In reference to date formats wrap your strings in mysql `TIMESTAMP()` to be sure they are being parsed properly.